# A expressão "digo isso" pode ser isolada por vírgulas?

Tags: expressões, pontuação, vírgula

Em alguns casos utilizo a expressão "digo isso" entre vírgulas. Por exemplo:

> A situação é bastante complicada, digo isso, pois já vi coisas assim acontecerem e ficarem sem solução.

Coloco uma vírgula depois porque a expressão vem antes de uma conjunção. Enfim, a minha dúvida é se essa expressão isolada entre vírgulas nesse contexto está gramaticalmente correta.

Comment: O *pois* pode ser usado em três conjunções: *conclusiva*, *explicativa* e *adversativa*. Como a frase — ao meu ver — é uma conclusão, a vírgula deve ser empregada antes e depois da conjunção, por exemplo `(...) complicada, digo isso, pois, já vi (...)`.

Comment: Não tenho a regra gramatical à mão me embasando mas não vejo sentido em colocar "digo isso" entre vírgulas. Correto para mim seria "A situação é bastante complicada. Digo isso pois (ou porque) já vi coisas acontecerem (...)". Digo o quê? Isso. Por quê? Porque já vi coisas acontecerem. Note que você não diz "Eu disse aquilo, porque estava bravo". Enfim, intuitivamente não vejo sentido nas vírgulas.

Comment: Concordo com o comentário acima, de @Piovezan. Alternativamente, eu usaria ponto e vírgula (`;`) para indicar continuidade de idéia: *A situação é bastante complicada; digo isso pois já vi coisas acontecerem (...)*

Comment: Concordo. Só uma coisa que eu não havia me atentado (até porque tinha pouca familiaridade com a regra): devido ao "digo" ser em tempo presente e não pretérito, acredito que o correto é "digo isto", e não "digo isso".